# Conditional Post-Build step in Jenkins without plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For my post-build step, I will be executing Sonar analysis (from SonarQube plugin) and a script that I wrote. I don't want this to run all the time and want to trigger the post-build step with a boolean parameter. Is there anyway to do this? Ideally, I want to have a checkbox that determines if the Post-Build step will execute in the Build-with-Configurations page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) to start further steps after a build. This can be done either manually (I think that's what you're looking for) or based on some logic you've defined.